# Incompatibilities sharing R code

Tags: r, collaboration

I have been having difficulty sharing R code with a collaborator and I'm wondering how to resolve this issue. My code will run properly for me but will not run for my collaborator and vice versa. I keep R/Rstudio and my packages up to date.

My collaborator uses R on their PC, while I use Rstudio on my mac. Are there any known incompatibilities between R/Rstudio or sharing R code between macs and PCs?

One hypothesis that I have is that this might be caused by old versions of packages. I know that my collaborator keeps R up to date, but I'm unsure about how they manage their packages.

For e.g. I use tidyverse for data manipulation and it seems that this in particular is a problem for them.

What are the best ways to successfully share code? Someone recently recommended that instead of using "library" to load packages that I might fix my problem using "require" instead.

Comment: R is a programming language. What IDE for R does your collaborator use on their PC? If you both keep R up-to-date then your code should open and run just fine for both of you. Otherwise one of you is mistaken (or lying).

Comment: There are minor differences in the behavior of R across OS X and Windows, such as the need to use `method="wininet"` in `download.files()` on Windows versus `method="curl"` on OS X. Generally speaking, however, a given package installed at the same release level across the two operating systems will behave the same way and produce the same results. I have R installations on OS X, Windows, and Ubuntu Linux and the y all produce the same results when the current release levels of packages are applied to each operating system.

Comment: The best way might be to use docker so you are both running on the same image build. But ignore whoever suggested to use "require" instead of "library". Its nearly always the wrong thing to do: https://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that both machines have the same packages at the same release levels, one can use the procedure described in Chris Eberwein's article [How to Upgrade R Without Losing Your Packages](http://www.datascienceriot.com/r/upgrade-R-packages/) that was posted to Data Science Riot. I'm reposting the non-Bioconductor steps so people can see the steps here on SO.

First, save the list of currently installed packages to an `.rda` file.

```
   tmp <- installed.packages()
   installedpkgs <- as.vector(tmp[is.na(tmp[,"Priority"]), 1])
   save(installedpkgs, file="installed_old.rda")
```

Second, install the latest version of R.

Third, reload the old packages and update.

```
tmp <- installed.packages()
installedpkgs.new <- as.vector(tmp[is.na(tmp[,"Priority"]), 1])
missing <- setdiff(installedpkgs, installedpkgs.new)
install.packages(missing)
update.packages()
```

To reinstall the Bioconductor packages, read the article at the URL linked above.

One way to confirm that the same versions of all packages are installed on multiple machines is to use the `sessionInfo()` function and compare the output from the each machine.

```
> library(tidyverse)
── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.2.1 ──
✔ ggplot2 2.2.1     ✔ purrr   0.2.4
✔ tibble  1.3.4     ✔ dplyr   0.7.4
✔ tidyr   0.7.2     ✔ stringr 1.2.0
✔ readr   1.1.1     ✔ forcats 0.2.0
── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] forcats_0.2.0   stringr_1.2.0   dplyr_0.7.4     purrr_0.2.4     readr_1.1.1    
[6] tidyr_0.7.2     tibble_1.3.4    ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14          cellranger_1.1.0      compiler_3.4.2       
 [4] plyr_1.8.4            bindr_0.1             tools_3.4.2          
 [7] lubridate_1.7.1       jsonlite_1.5          nlme_3.1-131         
 [10] gtable_0.2.0          lattice_0.20-35       pkgconfig_2.0.1      
 [13] rlang_0.1.4           psych_1.7.8           cli_1.0.0            
 [16] rstudioapi_0.7.0-9000 parallel_3.4.2        haven_1.1.0          
 [19] bindrcpp_0.2          xml2_1.1.1            httr_1.3.1           
 [22] hms_0.4.0             grid_3.4.2            glue_1.2.0           
 [25] R6_2.2.2              readxl_1.0.0          foreign_0.8-69       
 [28] modelr_0.1.1          reshape2_1.4.2        magrittr_1.5         
 [31] scales_0.5.0          rvest_0.3.2           assertthat_0.2.0     
 [34] mnormt_1.5-5          colorspace_1.3-2      stringi_1.1.6        
 [37] lazyeval_0.2.1        munsell_0.4.3         broom_0.4.3          
 [40] crayon_1.3.4         
>
```